# TouchID canceling should dismiss the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

For my app I need to save one page of it with TouchID. So the user is kinda forced to use TouchID or if the device does not support it, a password. If the user cancels the TouchID authentication, I want to View to disappear and get back to the root view. I already had that working, but somehow it does not work anymore and I really don't know why?! I just copied until the canceled option, the rest is does not matter I guess.

```
func authenticateUser() {

    let context = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?
    let reasonString = "Authentication is needed to access your App"

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error){

        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reasonString, reply: { (success, policyError) -> Void in
            if success {
                print("authentification successful")


                }

            }else{

                switch policyError!.code{
                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentification was canceled by the system")
                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was canceled by user")
                    self.navigationController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                //Yes I also tried popToRootViewController, still doesn't work    
}
```

Comment: try `popviewControlleranimated: true`

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention, I already tried that too... that also just makes the TouchID authentication disappear, but doesn't dismiss the view, so the user gets to see the view he shouldn't be seeing without authentication...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the evaluatePolicy call says:

"Reply block that is executed when policy evaluation finishes. This block is evaluated on a private queue internal to the framework in an unspecified threading context."

So the problem is that you are trying to call navigation from the wrong thread. You need to make that call on the UI thread. For example:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
     // Navigation goes here
}
```

Comment: Can you tell/show me how to do that? And I'm kinda surprised, cause like I said, it used to work, but after developing the app, it doesn't work anymore for some reason, even though I didn't change a single line of code inside this file.

Comment: Making calls that update the UI from a non-UI thread leads to unpredictable results, which explains how the behaviour can change without any code change.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it works perfect! I think I know what you mean, but still don't really understand why it worked perfectly 3 weeks ago (every single time I tested it, like 20 times) and now every single time does not work :D If I got your answer right, it must be kinda random?! Well, doesn't really matter, you fixed it, big thanks!!